# Using Off-The-Record and Trillian Astra together

Tags: windows, plugins, chat, trillian, encryption

Does anyone know how to use Off-the-Record (OTR) with Trillian Astra? I've found the OTR for Trillian plugin here:

http://trillianotr.kittyfox.net/

For the most part, it works and I can use OTR for chats with other people who initiate them or with people whose fingerprints I have. But I cannot initiate one myself to a user for whom I don't have a fingerprint.

Other users have referred to using the OTR icon/menu to initiate an OTR chat, but there is no OTR icon or menu in the conversations window.

I think this plugin was developed for a previous version of Trillian and not Astra (4.2).

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What build are you using? As i believe Trillian 4.2 Build 16 fixed any bug issues with OTR

Comment: I'm using Trillian 4.2 Build 18 Pro, and Trillian OTR plugin 0.5.0 (Build 160).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only solution I could figure out was to enable the "Require private messaging" option in the OTR plugin before initiating a chat, and then if your partner's client supports OTR, it will negotiate the fingerprint exchange.

But you have to disable this option before chatting with someone who doesn't have OTR, otherwise you'll get problems.

So you can do this to force a fingerprint exchange, and then un-check the option for normal use. Or ask the other person to initiate the exchange.

Oh well. Anyone have a better fix or workaround?

Or do I just have to wait and hope either the plugin developer or Trillian fix this? :D

EDIT:
Just stumbled upon this today. If you right click inside the box where you type, you get a menu that has the OTR options, including start an OTR conversation. How silly... but glad I found it.

Comment: Just wait but do not hope. Plugin dev is lost, trillian fix ... WHAT?!... Excuse me.. :P

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. At least the author did release the source for the OTR plugin. Maybe if I have time in the future, I'll see if I can fix it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is totally FUBAR. It's not intended to be used with the latest Astra, not even with Astra. I wrote some requests like other users did. Trillian doesn't care even a bit, just leave it as it is. So I have parted with Trillian, really one of the worst companies out there. (Don't get me wrong, this is not the simple issue and they don't care. For me, if it's a paid product, an epic fail.)

Clients with good OTR support:
Pidgin + pidgin-otr
bitlbee-otr
mcabber
(centerim (with custom build flag))
gajim (will get a recent addon soon.)

Comment: I've tried Pidgin but I really don't like the UI. 

The others you mentioned seem to be XMPP / Jabber only, and the reason I'm using Trillian is because of multi-network support.

It really is too bad that nobody has come up with a Windows version of Adium. It's fantastic and I do like ducks.

Comment: Adium == Pidgin. Its almost TOTALLY the same. Adium uses libpurple, Pidgin's base. What's the difference? ^^" (by the way I was messing around with trillian for a while until I could remove ALL that stupid theme, emoticons, whatsoever.. so annoying. I want to chat, to talk. Why is it so hard to understand? :/)